# Scons: run a make command as a dependency for a target

Tags: makefile, scons

I have a library that needs to by built as a dependency for my target.  The library is distributed with a Makefile and there's nothing special needed to build it other than to run:

```
make my_target
```

How would I run this command as part of my SConstruct file if my file looks something like:

```
env = Environment()
flags = env.ParseFlags( CCFLAGS + LDFLAGS )
env.MergeFlags( flags )
env.Program( target = 'my_prog', source = SRC )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `Command` builder with the name of the library as the target:

```
env.Command("other/lib/libother.a", "", "cd other && make my_target")
```

Be sure to add this library to your `Program` line:

```
env.Program(target="my_prog", source=SRC, LIBS=["other/lib/libother.a"])
```